# Shortcut to change playlist in Audacious

Tags: audacious

The Audacious music player presents playlist as tabs. File explorers like caja or nautilus provide very easy and useful shortcuts to change between tabs: <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>NUMBER</kbd>. Audacious lacks this functionality and I'm wondering if there is a way to change current playlist using only keyboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> as in most applications that use tabs.

Comment: It works like a charm. Why there's nothing about this in the documentation or in the shortcuts settings - I don't know.